# OpenLayers shows features at displaced location

Tags: openlayers

I am having an OpenLayers 6.9.0 map within a vue.js application.

The issue I am experiencing is, that features displayed on the map will be shown at a different location after panning or zooming into the map.
This behaviour is more obvious in zoom levels higher than 3 and when panning the map with "a little more speed". But this does not seem to be a strict criterion.

The features are basically brought to the map like this:

```
const reader = new GeoJSON()
const poiFeatures = await getPoiFeaturesAsFeatureCollection()
for (const poiFeature of poiFeatures.features) {
  const feature = reader.readFeature(poiFeature, { featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857', dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326' })
  layer.source.addFeature(feature)
}
```

This is the original location of the features after being drawn:

[image]

After panning the map to the east, the features are apparently displayed at the same pixel coordinates on the screen. Their absolute geographic coordinates stay the same:

[image]

After panning the map to the south:

[image]

Any ideas, what could cause this or workarounds to prevent it?

Comment: are you sure your points are in 4326?

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton I have double checked coordinates and I think they are ok. Incoming FeatureCollection feature looks like this '{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[9.32987995,52.47156765]},"properties":{..}', coordinates of a feature are 1038597.4851963728,6885844.20036069.

Comment: Even if coordinates were incorrectly transformed between projections they would not change after that.  This might be an issue with incorrect pixel ratios or incorrect css causing rendering to be misplaced.  It would be difficult to know without a working example which reproduces the error.

Comment: @Mike Thanks. It could be hard to provide a reduced working example when it is not clear what causes this issue. However I will try to do that. Can you elaborate what you mean by incorrect pixel ratios and on which part css could probably cause this?